# Adding the total amount of each row together

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, row, jquery-calculation

I would like to add all the rows together using mvc ,the rows are name and total spending ,these 2 rows are saved inside database,  now i would like to add one more row which is total spending for all.  May I know how could I get it done? 
To sum up , i would need to have a grand total column which calculates all the total spending of each person . 
Sorry I am new to programming.

Example:

Name: James

**Total Spending :** $5

Name: Tina

**Total Spending :** $15

Then there will be a **Total Spending for everyone** which calculate both james and tina spending , so how do I get the calculation for all the total spending ?

These are the codes:
Currently I could only get the total price for one row only with

`foreach (var DataSheet in db.Query(query)){
var spending = DataSheet.Spending;
totalSpending = spending + 2
}`
I need to add the total spending for 2 different people and put it inside the AllTSpending row

Comment: how do I make a calculation for 2 different rows ?

Comment: Create one property in your model and assign value form controller. whenever you want to show.

Comment: Explain whole scenario, and add your code and where you stuck, so we can get more idea.

Comment: But how do I calculate the 2 different rows ?
Currently I could only get the total price for one row only with 
 foreach (var DataSheet in db.Query(query))
                                                    {
var spending = DataSheet.Spending;
totalSpending = spending + 2
}

Comment: this has nothing to do with MVC. You need a data access tier. A framework such as Entity Framework.